# Portfolio Optimization R - error

Tags: r, optimization, finance, portfolio

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I have trying to figure this out for 3 days now. I am getting this error every time I try to run the portfolio optimization and can't figure it out.

```
Error in assign(".objectivestorage", list(), envir = as.environment(.storage)) : 
  object '.storage' not found
```

I'm also getting this warning usually at the second and third objectives:

```
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(le) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

Here is my code:

```
##Import Dataset
setwd("D:\\Dropbox\\FUND - SSIF\\Portfolio Analysis Package")
Stocktrak<- Return.read("SSIF_Data.csv", frequency = "d")
# Create Objects for data and column names

R <- Stocktrak[, 1:17]
colnames(returns) <- c("JEC", "BNS", "AAPL", "PEG", "SLB", "TSM", "HD",
  "MON", "GWO", "TOT", "XPH", "CVS", "UNP", "KORS", "GNTX", "NWC", "WFC")
funds <- colnames(R)

# Create an initial portfolio object with leverage and box constraints
init <- portfolio.spec(assets=funds)
init <- add.constraint(portfolio=init, type="leverage", min_sum=0.99, max_sum=1.01)
init <- add.constraint(portfolio=init, type="box", min=0.01, max=0.65)

# Create Objectives for eq_meanETL Portfolio Optimization
eq_meanETL <- add.objective(portfolio=init, type="return", name="mean")
eq_meanETL <- add.objective(portfolio=eq_meanETL, type="risk", name="ETL", arguments=list(p=0.95))
eq_meanETL <- add.objective(portfolio=eq_meanETL, type="risk_budget", name="ETL", min_concentration=TRUE, arguments=list(p=0.95))

# Optimize Portfolio
opt_eq_meanETL <- optimize.portfolio(R=R, portfolio=eq_meanETL, optimize_method="DEoptim", search_size=2000, trace=TRUE, traceDE=5)
```

Comment: I could not reproduze your error/ warning. That code works for me with simulated returns `nrs=600
Stocktrak=matrix(rnorm(nrs*17,0.1,0.05),nrow = nrs)
#set any date
Stocktrak<- as.xts(Stocktrak,order.by = seq.Date(from=as.Date("2016-03-21")-nrs,by=1,length.out =nrs ))

R <- Stocktrak[, 1:17]
colnames(R) <- c("JEC",   "BNS", "AAPL",  "PEG",  "SLB",  "TSM",  "HD",   "MON",  "GWO",  "TOT",  "XPH",  "CVS",  "UNP",  "KORS", "GNTX", "NWC", "WFC")
funds <- colnames(R)`

Answer (score 3):

place the following before `optimize.portfolio`

```
.storage <<- new.env()
```

Answer (score -1):

Editing

Change the trace = FALSE

It will work. First time here.

## Optimize Portfolio

opt_eq_meanETL <- optimize.portfolio(R=R, portfolio=eq_meanETL, optimize_method="DEoptim", search_size=2000, trace=FALSE, traceDE=5)

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the answer. First time here.

Inside the package source code we have the following message:

        #we can't pass trace=TRUE into constrained objective with DEoptim, because it expects a single numeric return

That is why we receive the error